# Make WCF DateTime Compatible for Java client

Tags: c#, java

I'm designing a WCF Service which will be consumed by Java client by returning an array of object .

I design a small Java application to display the output object collection fields.

all fine except the DateTime which is displayed as follows:

java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1370969700000,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="GMT+01:00",offset=3600000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null],firstDayOfWeek=2,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=4,ERA=1,YEAR=2013,MONTH=5,WEEK_OF_YEAR=24,WEEK_OF_MONTH=2,DAY_OF_MONTH=11,DAY_OF_YEAR=162,DAY_OF_WEEK=3,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=2,AM_PM=1,HOUR=5,HOUR_OF_DAY=17,MINUTE=55,SECOND=0,MILLISECOND=0,ZONE_OFFSET=3600000,DST_OFFSET=0]

Could you at least guide me  about some best practice or attribute to add in my Service to prevent this issue?

Is there any Java turn around?

Comment: What "issue" are you trying to prevent?

Comment: how DateTime is displayed

Comment: Please post the code, especially including the variable declarations and the statement that is causing that output. It looks like you're just calling `toString` on a `Calendar` instance somewhere and not happy about the format; is that correct?

Comment: Absolutely you are right, many thanks i solve the issue, sorry to desturb you with this stup.... question ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Java Calendar objects gives you all the information you need to precisely definte the moment in time: the time itself (internally in millisecs since the epoch 01/01/1970), the timezone, ....

So there is nothing for you to do to change this behaviour, except that in your code you can obtain a "Date" object (also containing the time) from the calendar object you obtained using the getTime() method.

Comment: Thanks it works, i'am diving into JAva world just to get rid of client request round-trip, to be sure the integration will works, aside that i'am full time .NET developer